# Backbone.Model: set collection as property

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I'm new with backbone and faced the following problems. I'm trying to emulate some sort of "has many relation". To achieve this I'm adding following code to initialize method in  the model:

```
defaults: {
  name: '',
  tags: []
},
initialize: function() {
  var tags = new TagsCollection(this.get('tags'));
  tags.url = this.url() + "/tags";
  return this.set('tags', tags, {
    silent: true
  });
}
```

This code works great if I fetch models through collection. As I understand, first collection gets the data and after that this collection populates models with this data. But when I try to load single model I get my property being overridden with plain Javascript array.

```
m = new ExampleModel({id: 15})
m.fetch() // property tags get overridden after load
```

and response:

```
{
  name: 'test',
  tags: [
     {name: 'tag1'}, 
     {name: 'tag2'}
  ]
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

One more question. Is there a way to check if model is loaded or not. Yes, I know that we can add callback to the fetch method, but what about something like this model.isLoaded or model.isPending?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) remove return before this.set , for more info http://backbonejs.org/#changelog read 1.1.0 section. 2) model.isLoaded - not existing for sure, is this property should flag is fetch completed or something else ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. 1) I have already removed "return" from the initialize method (it was generated by coffeescript), but of course it doesn't help me to solve problem. 2) You understood me right. I mean some method that could help me to understand if model was fetched or not.

Comment: could you please attach code how you load single model, looks like i got what is the reason. 2)i could provide model.isLoaded realization based on sync event if you are intrested in

Answer (score 0):

> "when I try to load single model I get my property being overridden with plain Javascript array"

You can override the [Model#parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method to keep your collection getting overwritten:

```
parse: function(attrs) {

    //reset the collection property with the new
    //tags you received from the server
    var collection = this.get('tags');
    collection.reset(attrs.tags);

    //replace the raw array with the collection
    attrs.tags = collection;

    return attrs;
}
```

---

> "Is there a way to check if model is loaded or not?"

You could compare the model to its defaults. If the model is at its default state (save for its `id`), it's not loaded. If it doesn't, it's loaded:

```
isLoaded: function() {

    var defaults = _.result(this, 'defaults');
    var current  = _.wíthout(this.toJSON(), 'id');

    //you need to convert the tags to an array so its is comparable
    //with the default array. This could also be done by overriding
    //Model#toJSON
    current.tags = current.tags.toJSON();

    return _.isEqual(current, defaults);
}
```

Alternatively you can hook into the `request`, `sync` and `error` events to keep track of the model syncing state:

```
initialize: function() {
    var self = this;

    //pending when a request is started
    this.on('request', function() {
        self.isPending = true;
        self.isLoaded = false;
    });

    //loaded when a request finishes
    this.on('sync', function() {
        self.isPending = false;
        self.isLoaded = true;
    });

    //neither pending nor loaded when a request errors
    this.on('error', function() {
        self.isPending = false;
        self.isLoaded = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now it works when I fetch one model but it doesn't work with collection. It's kinda weird that when collection creates models first it call "parse" method and after that  "initialize" method. So when I get models through collection I can't access property "tags" because it's not initialized yet.